# AWS Cloudformation - Create initial folders in EFS

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-cloudformation, nfs, amazon-efs

I am using AWS cloudformation to create an EFS file system. I want to have some intial folders in the file system before mounting it to any instances. Can I achieve this though the cloud formation code? How can I create a folder in my EFS through code?

Following is the code I have so far.

```
{
  "efs01": {
    "type": "efs",
    "depends_on": [],
    "persistent": "true",
    "descriptor": {
      "Resources" : {
        "SecurityGroup" : {
          "Type": "Pipeline::SecurityGroup",
          "Properties" : {
            "IngressRules" : [ { "sources": [ "app01","app02" ], "ports":["TCP:NFS"] } ]
          }
        },
        "FileSystem" : {
          "Type" : "AWS::EFS::FileSystem",
          "Properties" : {
            "ThroughputMode": "bursting",
            "ProvisionedThroughputInMibps": null
          }
        },
        "AccessPointResource": {
          "Type": "AWS::EFS::AccessPoint",
          "Properties": {
            "FileSystemId": {
              "Ref": "FileSystem"
            },
            "PosixUser": {
              "Uid": "ec2-user",
              "Gid": "ec2-user"
            },
            "RootDirectory": {
              "CreationInfo": {
                "OwnerGid": "root",
                "OwnerUid": "root",
                "Permissions": "0744"
              },
              "Path": "/ap1"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: CloudFormation can't use EFS directly -- you'll need some logic layer to do it for you. You could probably create an [AWS Lambda-backed custom resource - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources-lambda.html), which is a Lambda function that is triggered by CloudFormation. It could mount the EFS filesystem and then run commands to create directories. It's a bit fiddly to write Custom Resources.

Comment: Thanks, I am looking at the code at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-efs-accesspoint.html . Why I need an initial folder is to create an access point to my efs. If I create the access point, without already having the rootdirectory, will  create the rootdirectory in efs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I create a folder in my EFS through code?

You **don't have to do anything**. AWS will create `/ap1` for you automatically on the EFS. But any application that is going to use your `AccessPointResource` will not see it. Instead, they will be bound to `/ap1` and never be able to see what's at `/` of the EFS.

This means that for any application that mounts EFS using your `AccessPointResource`, the root of the mount is `/`. `/ap1` will only be visible to access points that use `"Path": "/"`.

Comment: Thanks, to be clear (not related to the original question), will it create  user and group that I will specify at "PosixUser" section.
Also if I mount the efs without using access point, should I see 'ap1' folder?

Comment: @ChamilaWijayarathna Yes, for the second question. For the first one, I'm not too sure. You can make new SO question with specific details regarding the PosixUser .

Comment: I don't see ap1 folder when I mounted my file system without using the access point. I thought missing folder caused access point creation to fail. Should be a different issue then. Thanks

Comment: @ChamilaWijayarathna Can you create new access point with `"Path": "/"` and use that to mount your efs?

Comment: I prefer to use a folder, so I can have few folders and allow my apps to access only the content that each app requires by mounting via access points.